# Why are the cardinality of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ the same?

Tags: cardinals, real-numbers

As I study the first part of abstract algebra, I have a question: why $\left\vert{\mathbb R}\right\vert = \left\vert{\mathbb R^2}\right\vert$?

And moreover, I knew the fact that $\left\vert{\mathbb R}\right\vert = \left\vert{\mathbb R^n}\right\vert$.

Does the equality apply to any infinite set?
How can I prove them?

Comment: @AlexMathers Not fully duplicate. The question is also whether $|X^n|=|X|$ if $X$ is an infinite set.

Comment: There you can see that if you accept the axiom of choice (which many do) then if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite and $|X|=|Y|$ then $|X\times Y| = |X|=|Y|$. Otherwise (if you don't accept AC) you can't tell in general if $|X^n|=|X|$.

Comment: @skyking: But if $X$ is some iterated power-set of $\mathbb{N}$, then ZF (without AC) is more than enough and the proof is simple too, which is relevant for $\mathbb{R} \approx \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @user21820 But all infinite sets need not be iterated power-sets of $\mathbb N$. The question also was about if this is true for **any** infinite set.

Comment: @skyking: Of course, which is why I said my comment is relevant for the real numbers. A lot of people think that one needs AC to prove such results but in applied mathematics very little (perhaps none) needs AC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existence of *space-filling curves* shows that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be at most that of $\mathbb{R}$. A space-filling curve in a curve parametrized by a surjective mapping $s: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $s$ is surjective, we must conclude that $|\mathbb{R}^n| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$.

More generally, to show that we have $|A^n| = |A|$ for any infinite set $A$ and finite $n \geq 1$, it is enough to show that $|A \times A| = |A|$, since the general case then follows by a trivial inductive argument.

To prove the result, consider the family $\mathcal{F}$ of those functions $f$ such that $f: X \times X \rightarrow X$, where $X$ is a subset of $A$. $\mathcal{F}$ is non-empty, for if $X$ is a countable subset of $A$, then the usual dovetailing argument tells us that such an $f$ exist. It is also easy to see that $\mathcal{F}$ can be equipped with a partial order $\sqsubseteq$, namely that of extension: $f_1 \sqsubseteq f_2$ if $\mathrm{dom}(f_1) \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f_2)$ and whenever $f_1(x) = y$, then also $f_2(x) = y$. Because $\mathcal{F}$ is partially ordered, we know from Zorn's lemma that it has a maximal element $f_{max}$. So let $\mathrm{dom}(f_{max}) = X$. All that is left is then to show that $|X| = |A|$.

Suppose $X$ had strictly smaller cardinality than $A$. But then, since $|A| = \max(|X|,|A \setminus X|)$ we must have that $|A| = |A \setminus X|$ and therefore that $|X| < |A \setminus X|$. This then means that we can find a $Y \subset A \setminus X$ of the same cardinality as $X$. But now consider the sets $X \times Y$, $Y \times X$ and $Y \times Y$. Each of these sets is infinite and has the same cardinality as $X \times X$ and therefore also the same cardinality as $X$ and as $Y$. Therefore we have

$$ |X \times Y \cup Y \times X \cup Y \times Y| = |Y|$$

But $X \times Y \cup Y \times X \cup Y \times Y = (X \cup Y) \times (X \cup Y)$, so this means that we can extend $f_{max}$ such that its domain is $(X \cup Y) \times (X \cup Y)$, and that is a contradiction, since $f_{max}$ was assumed to be maximal.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of a real number in decimal notation: an infinite sequence of digits with a decimal point somewhere in there. Now you can take $n$ (e.g. $n=3$) such numbers and interleave their digits like this:

```
      1  2.  3  5  6…
  1  3  7 . 2  7  3 …
    9  3  .1  5  8  …
⇒ 10931372.123575836…
```

So this way you have turned a triple of real numbers into a single real number in a reversible fashion. To make this rigorous you'd have to consider special cases like $0.999… = 1$, but the above should convey the general idea in an intuitive way.

For $n=\infty$ this argument no longer holds in this fashion. And it's not that trivial there, either, since it depends on the *kind* of infinity. Most likely you have contable infinity in mind there, I guess, so you are asking about $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: And $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ of course. But I think he's asking whether $|X|=|X^2|$ holds for every infinite $X.$

Comment: @bof: Right now I'm not sure how to *intuitively* show that $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$, so I'm not sure I agree with “of course”. But you are right, now that I read the question again, infinite base sets are more likely what this question is about.

Comment: Well, if you think of a real number (loosely) as an infinite sequence of digits, then you can think of an infinite sequence of real numbers as an infinite two-dimensional array of digits, so it boils down to $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0.$

Comment: Could you expand or give a reference on the $n=\infty$ case? You are saying both the same and a larger cardinality are possible depending on how the limit is taken?